# How to group and calculate in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have df like below

```
customer class  score
A          a      10
A          b      20
B          a      40
B          b      50
```

I would like to group, transform and calculate like this.

```
customer  score(b-a)
A           10
B           10
```

I couldnt figure out how to calculate..

```
df.groupby(df.customer)
```

If someone has experienced such aggregation,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby("customer").diff()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @HenryYik's comment, or you can use `pivot`:

```
(df.pivot(index='customer', columns='class', values='score')
   .assign(score=lambda x: x['b']-x['a'])
)
```

Output:

```
class      a   b  score
customer               
A         10  20     10
B         40  50     10
```

Comment: `.drop(['a','b'])` to top it off almost identical to my own answer! `df.groupby(["customer", "class"])["score"].sum().unstack().assign(
    score=lambda x: x["b"] - x["a"]
).drop(["a", "b"], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, group by over customer and apply a custom function

```
def get_score(temp):
    map_score = dict(zip(temp['class'], temp['score'])) # mapping of class and score for each customer
    return map_score['b'] - map_score['a']
df.groupby("customer").apply(get_score)
```

This will result in expected answer.